# Django cannot change password error didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I create form for change password like this.

forms.py

```
class PasswordChangeForm(forms.Form):

    password = forms.CharField(max_length=32,required=True,widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    repassword = forms.CharField(max_length=32,required=True,widget=forms.PasswordInput,label="Password Confirmation")

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(PasswordChangeForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        repassword = cleaned_data.get("repassword")

        if password != repassword:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Password and Confirm Password does not match"
            )
```

In views.py I save new password like this code
views.py

```
def changePassword(request):

    username = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        if request.method == 'POST':

            form = PasswordChangeForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                username = request.user.username
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

                user.set_password(password)
                user.save()
                messages.success(request, "Your password has been changed successfuly.!")
            
                return redirect('/changePassword')

            else:
                print(form.errors.as_data())

        else:
            form=PasswordChangeForm()
            
        return render(request,'changepassword_form.html',{'form':form})
```

It show error like this.

```
ValueError at /changePassword
The view device.views.changePassword didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

The password was changed after show error. It auto logout and I can login with new password but it not redirect to form. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that after you changed the password the user is not authenticated anymore, add `@login_required` instead of checking whether user is authenticated.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def changePassword(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
```